# Data structure for a file

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, file-handling

I have a document(file) and i want to read it line by line and split into a string(word).Now the problem is that i want to assign an index or number from 0 to so on to each word in a line and as for the new line, i want to assign it again an index or number from 0 to so on.

***File Example:

i have a dog

WDC is the capital of USA

mount Everest is the highest mountain

***Required Output:

0:i 1:have 2:a 3:dog

0:WDC 1:is 2:the 3:capital 4:of 5:USA

0:mount 1:Everest 2:is 3:the 4:highest 5:mountain

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(' ');
}
```

Now what should i do?

Comment: You could save `words` in an `ArrayList<String []>`.

Comment: ArrayList<String []> list= new ArrayList<String []>();
why cant i add string to list , doesnt show .add method

Comment: You never tagged a language. Looks like Java code but looking again, it looks like C#?

Comment: sorry not to mention
it is c#

Comment: In C# you would use `List<string []>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save words in an `List<string []>`.

```c#
List<string []> data = new List<string []>();
// Read file
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    data.Add(line.Split(' '));
}
// Print results
for (int line = 0; line < data.Count; line++) {
    Console.Write("{0}: ", line);
    for (int word = 0; word < data[line].Length; word++) {
        Console.Write("{0}:{1} ", word, data[line][word]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```